# How to remove a filter from Git

Tags: git

I want to remove a filter that added to Git. The command `git config --list` shows the filter I added

```
filter.spabs.clean=expand --initial -t 4
filter.spabs.smudge=expand --initial -t 4
filter.spabs.required
```

How can I remove it? Where does Git store the filters? I have verified `.gitconfig` and I don't have a `.git/info/attributes` file.

Comment: If those entries are absent from your `~/.gitconfig` file, look for them in the `.git/config` file of your repo; delete whichever entry(ies) you want.

Comment: @Jubobs I done that but I got the same result when I do `git config --list`

Comment: Have you deleted the offending entries from your `.git/config` file and saved the file?

Comment: @Jubobs Yes I deleted all the filter section.

Comment: As Frederic points out in his answer, the offending line may be in the global  (i.e. user-level) Git config file, which is usually `~/.gitconfig`; run `git config --list --global` to check whether they're indeed in that file. Or they may be in the system-wide Git config file; run `git config --list --system` to check.

Comment: @Jubobs they are in the system-wide

Comment: then you should be able to remove from the ~/.gitconfig file

Comment: @FredericHenri My system-wide config file is on /etc folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For removing in *all* [config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) files (without having to look for the key):

```
git config --unset-all filter.spabs.clean
git config --unset-all filter.spabs.smudge
git config --unset-all filter.spabs.required
```

As illustrated in "[`git credential.helper=cache` never forgets the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18542920/6309)", you can do a:

```
sudo git config --system --unset-all filter.spabs.clean
sudo git config --system --unset-all filter.spabs.smudge
sudo git config --system --unset-all filter.spabs.required
```

That would remove those keys from `/etc/gitconfig`.

Comment: @user230137 what git version are you using? On which OS?

Comment: The config file that contains theses command is /etc/gitconfig. git version 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. It's privilege issue I think.

Comment: @user230137 OK. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

so you need to know where they are defined, rather than `git config --list` you can run the 2 commands

```
git config --local --list
git config --global --list
```

For local filters, you need to look under `.git/config` file

For global filters, you need to look under `~/.gitconfig` file