# Can't clone private repos using command line clone command (despite owning them)

Tags: github

Using command line, I can clone my public repos but cannot clone my private repos.

I have many private repos - and have been branching, committing, etc with no problems. But, today things seem to have broken. When I try to clone a repo, I get

Cloning into 'XYZRepo'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/user/XYZRepo.git/' not found

(uname and repo names have been changed).

I checked 
* the clone address is correct (I copied it directly from the repo)
* git config --global user.name (and user.email) are correct
Also, I do not have any .git directory in the folders I'm trying to clone to.

Any ideas on what could be going on here?

Comment: Can yoi view the repo directly from GitHub using your credentials?

Comment: the source of the problem seems to be with credential management. If I clone with the full username:password@ format (i.e. git clone https://<username>:<password>@github.com/user/XYZRepo.git" it works. I read up on credential management... and still don't understand how I see what credentials are stored and being used. I just reinstalled git and github clients. What a pain.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem seems to have been the credential management.

If I cloned with the full username:password@ format (i.e. git clone https://:@github.com/user/XYZRepo.git" then the repo is found and cloned without generating any error.

To get to the source of the problem I read up on credential management... and still don't understand how I see what credentials are stored and being used (it's "magic"). So, I just reinstalled git and github clients - and the "magic" seems to be back.

NOTE: "--unset-all" might be a possible solution as well [git credential.helper=cache never forgets the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157583/git-credential-helper-cache-never-forgets-the-password)

Comment: I just tried this "unsetting" approach, and it doesn't seem to work. To fix the problem (without reinstalling) what I've found out is that I once I use the full clone link (with username and password) it works... and thereafter, I don't need to mention the username and password again.