# wrong passphrase 3 times: git doesn't ask for passphrase anymore

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-agent

I wanted to push on a remote git repository. I typed the wrong passphrase three times. I have created a new ssh key and registered the new public key on the repository server.
But the ssh agent doesn't prompt for the passphrase. It just keeps telling me:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

How can I solve this problem under ubuntu?

**Edit**

As it was suggested, I tried `ssh-add`

```
sadik@sadix:~$ cd .ssh/
sadik@sadix:~/.ssh$ ls
config  github_rsa  github_rsa.pub  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  keys.zip  known_hosts
sadik@sadix:~/.ssh$ ssh-add 
Enter passphrase for /home/sadik/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/sadik/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/sadik/.ssh/id_rsa)
sadik@sadix:~/.ssh$ 
sadik@sadix:~/.ssh$ cd
sadik@sadix:~$ cd some/git-repo/
sadik@sadix:~/some/git-repo/$ git push -u bitbucket master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I should add that this git repository has been cloned from github (not owned by me). I want to push it on my private repository on bitbucket.
I don't know whether this can lead to permission problems, but my first problem is that ssh does not prompt for a passphrase. Even after reboot or log out.

**Edit**

As Jakuje kindly suggested I entered the command `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push -u bitbucket master` to get the client logs. This is the end of the output:

```
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/sadik/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sadik/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/sadik/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sadik/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/sadik/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sadik/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/sadik/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

For whatever reason it searches for a pubkey `id_dsa`, so I copied `id_rsa` to `id_dsa` and tried it again.
Now it prompts for a passphrase! But ... when I enter the wrong passphrase, it asks me again. When I enter the correct one, it says permission denied.

```
$ git push -u bitbucket master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sadik/.ssh/id_dsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sadik/.ssh/id_dsa': 
Enter passphrase for key '/home/sadik/.ssh/id_dsa': 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

1. What's wrong with the permissions?
2. Why is it looking for `id_dsa` instead of `id_rsa`?

Comment: Are your keys (public and private) in your `~/.ssh` directory? Did you `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`?

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink yes and yes. It worked perfectly well until I forgot the passphrase and guessed wrong for multiple times. So I created a new one. The only problem is, that it doesn't prompt for the passphrase. It just takes the wrong one I entered before

Comment: It is using rsa few lines above and it is rejected. Make sure it is really the key you set up to bitbucket, restart you ssh-agent and try again.

Comment: have you looked through the documentation at '$git help credentials' ? Looks to me like you may have several old credentials cached and it is failing to find their keys under ~/.ssh/

Comment: @DougCoburn Yes, I tried to reset credential.helper (like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18542920/2013672) but that seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Things look complicated enough that it may be worth starting all over:

1. Remove all the keys in *~/.ssh* that you don't need (if there are keys that you want to keep, consider moving them to a different directory for now).
2. If *~/.ssh/config* exists, check that it doesn't have suspicious lines.
3. If you are using *ssh-agent*, remove all keys using `ssh-add -D`. Check that there are no keys using `ssh-add -l`. If you see any output, you are suffering from [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=472477). Log out, log in, and verify that `ssh-add -l` produces no output.
4. Run `ls -al ~/.ssh` and check that there are no keys there.
5. Create a new key using `ssh-keygen`. Press enter when it asks for the output file to use the default, then type the passphrase twice.
6. Run `ls -al ~/.ssh` and check that *id_rsa* and *id_rsa.pub* exist.
7. Remove existing keys from Bitbucket.
8. Add the contents of *~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub* to Bitbucket.
9. Test the connection using `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org`. If it fails, post the output of `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org`.
10. Check that git commands works.

> Why is it looking for `id_dsa` instead of `id_rsa`?

SSH tries several keys until it finds one that works. It tried `id_rsa`, the key was rejected, so it went on to try `id_dsa`.

Credit to [@Leon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478009/) for mentioning *ssh-add*.

Comment: I didn't mention `ssh-agent` (only `ssh-add`). In any case, your answer is so much more elaborate and helpful that I am going to remove mine.

Comment: @Leon: Thank you! Please don't remove your answer though, it's good to have your personal experience on record. I've updated my answer regarding ssh-agent vs. ssh-add.

Comment: Thank you. Still don't know what went wrong, but starting all over sometimes is a good idea.

Comment: @Sadik: Thanks for the bounty. Is it working now though?

Comment: @tom yes, thanks. In addition to your steps I also created a new directory and did a git init on it, and copied all the files except the git related ones into the new directory.

Answer (score 4):

> I forgot the passphrase and guessed wrong for multiple times. So I created a new one.

I read that as you had a key that worked, you created a new one and you are wondering why it does not work.

You need to copy the public key to the server's `authorized_keys`.

Comment: that's what I meant when I wrote `"... and registered the new public key on the repository server"`. I wonder why the command line does not ask for a passphrase and assumes that I don't have access, based on the earlier tries.

Comment: It does not assume anything. If you set it up correcly, it should work. Post the debug logs frpm server and client.

Comment: There is not much to do right or wrong. Server is on bitbucket.org. I don't see any logs there. I have created a new key pair and pasted the pubkey to bitbucket. That's all.

Comment: I don't see any client log

Comment: What is the new key that you put into the bitbucket? `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git push -u bitbucket master` will generate your debug log.