# git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive). when pulling/pushing from gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

I searched in Stackoverflow but nothing seems helpful

I am getting the following error

```
git pull --tags origin dev
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

I have a private repository on gitlab, I added ssh key both to gitlab account and my laptop

I do not think there is a dismatch in my ssh, as I am able to clone the private repository to my laptop, but I am not able to push/pull changes and the error above appears

I run the command `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` and got the following output:

```
  OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [172.65.251.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:JNwiKdEh1lGQm2Mn0yByyWHQZvNThBIXFYdWbFeA79Q C:\\Users\\ASUS/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\ASUS/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to gitlab.com ([172.65.251.78]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /authorized_keys %u %k:1: key options: command user-rc
debug1: Remote: /authorized_keys %u %k:1: key options: command user-rc
Welcome to GitLab, @arajab!
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2604, received 2792 bytes, in 0.7 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3477.7, received 3728.8
debug1: Exit status
 0
```

Comment: `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` ?

Comment: @phd I updated my question, your help is appreciated

Comment: You're authenticated as user `arajab`. Your ssh key is ok. If the problem with `git pull` persists I suspects `git` runs a different `ssh` that doesn't authenticate.

Comment: the username is correct, how can I find out whether git is running the correct ssh? @phd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25388499/7976758 : `GIT_TRACE=2 git pull origin dev` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+trace+ssh

Comment: May be `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull origin dev`

Comment: Does this answer your question? The error message is not the same, but the symptoms look similar: [wrong passphrase 3 times: git doesn't ask for passphrase anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442869/wrong-passphrase-3-times-git-doesnt-ask-for-passphrase-anymore)