# Git don't request password when clone a bitbucket private repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I use my mac to clone a private repo on Bitbucket. In the first, it request password. But, in the next time, it didn't request for password.

And I can clone any others private repo of my account. Maybe, my mac saved password and use it whenever I have request to my repo. I worry that when I clone my private repo in others mac. My password will be saved in them.

How to delete it?

Comment: Did you run this line `git config credential.helper store`, after the first time when it asked for password ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git credential.helper=cache never forgets the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157583/git-credential-helper-cache-never-forgets-the-password)

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna No, I don't run.

Comment: @phd This answer is don't work for me. @@

Answer (score 1):

This link may help:
https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Git by default saves password in cache for 15 minutes.